# I am trying to install log4db2 utility in db2 for procedure logging but I am getting error mentioned below

Tags: db2

> DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL0601N The name of the object to be created is identical
>   to the existing name "LOG_CONF_BP" of type "BUFFERPOOL".
>   SQLSTATE=42710

How to remove pre-existed "LOG_CONF_BP" of type "BUFFERPOOL" in db2 database? Is there any other way to define logging for my stored procedures?